# Can't mkdir or open files on server, even with 777 permissions

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.3

I see that similar questions have been answered on Stack Overflow, but the solutions haven't fixed my particular problem, so I have to ask...

I have an app that needs to make directories and modify files outside the site directory. This works find on the production server.

After spinning up a test server with the exact same version of Ubuntu and PHP, I'm getting errors on the staging server when it tries to open files or create directories.

Here are the errors:

`mkdir() [http://php.net/function.mkdir]: Permission denied`

`fopen(/root/Dropbox/Backend/Booth-01/settings.sh) [http://php.net/function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

### Things I have tried:

- checking the username running the application (it's `www-data`)
- changing the owner of the external directory recursively to `www-data`
- changing permissions on the directory to 777 (I know, this is a bad idea, but I was just trying it to see if that would help until I figured out what the issue was and will change the permissions to something more restrictive once I get it working)
- checking the **umask** value. It was set to 0002, which shouldn't give me problems. Just for kicks, I tried changing it to 0000 and it didn't help.
- checking to make sure PHP's **safe mode** wasn't enabled.
- checking to make sure that nothing was specified in `open_basedir`. In any case, if that was the issue, it would throw a different error message.

I can't think of what to try next and I'm hoping that someone else is seeing something that I'm not.

---

Ubuntu 12.04.5 x64

PHP 5.3.10

Answer (score 0):

It's not only the folder itself you have to have permissions on. You should also check the parent folders. I think, if you check this, this will fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah, the parent folders are also owned by `www-data` and their permissions are also (temporarily) set to 777, so that doesn't seem like it's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an external drive (see if it shows up in `mount`) then you may have to remount it. An auto-mounted external drive can thwart permissions

```
sudo umount <moint-point>
sudo mount /dev/<device> <new-moint-point>
```